# backtrace in android crash log is not readable

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, backtrace, crash-log

My android game keeps crashing without readable backtrace in crash logs.
Here are some sample crash logs, does anyone have any idea how to trace this bug?

By the way, the game is developed using cocos2d-x running Lua script.

```
A/libc(23865): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x5e0a5024 (code=2), thread 23911 (Thread-5252)
I/DEBUG(252): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG(252): Build fingerprint: 'Xiaomi/armani/armani:4.3/JLS36C/JHCCNBH45.0:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG(252): Revision: '0'
I/DEBUG(252): pid: 23865, tid: 23911, name: Thread-5252  >>> com.gamedo.hlw.gfan <<<
I/DEBUG(252): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 5e0a5024
I/DEBUG(252):     r0 000000f1  r1 62c8c0f0  r2 62c8c198  r3 62c96d28
I/DEBUG(252):     r4 000000f2  r5 00000101  r6 00000000  r7 fffffff4
I/DEBUG(252):     r8 62cde188  r9 fffffffb  sl 62cc72e8  fp 00000000
I/DEBUG(252):     ip 00000000  sp 61028a00  lr 5ea0fd1c  pc 5e0a5024  cpsr 20000010
I/DEBUG(252):     d0  62d355dc62d35540  d1  0504800104008021
I/DEBUG(252):     d2  0700802106007ffc  d3  62d355dc62d35540
I/DEBUG(252):     d4  3fe0a3bed43ed000  d5  408f400000000000
I/DEBUG(252):     d6  0000000900000000  d7  3ce2010624dd2f1a
I/DEBUG(252):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG(252):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG(252):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG(252):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG(252):     d16 603f2754603f272c  d17 603f2788603f2770
I/DEBUG(252):     d18 603f22b0603f2240  d19 603f236c603f22c4
I/DEBUG(252):     d20 603f244c603f23d8  d21 603f258c603f24e4
I/DEBUG(252):     d22 603f2648603f25a8  d23 603f2700603f26e4
I/DEBUG(252):     d24 3f56c16c16c76a94  d25 3f80ebb74dbd97f2
I/DEBUG(252):     d26 408f480000000000  d27 3fc510036313e9c4
I/DEBUG(252):     d28 3fe0000000000000  d29 0000000000000001
I/DEBUG(252):     d30 fff0000000000000  d31 4000000000000000
I/DEBUG(252):     scr 28000012
I/DEBUG(252): backtrace:
I/DEBUG(252):     #00  pc 00095024  [stack:23883]
I/DEBUG(252):     #01  pc 00007d18  <unknown>
I/DEBUG(252): stack:
I/DEBUG(252):          610289c0  00007fd9  
I/DEBUG(252):          610289c4  60427cdc  /data/app-lib/com.gamedo.hlw.gfan-1/libcocos2dlua.so
I/DEBUG(252):          610289c8  6247d1c0  
I/DEBUG(252):          610289cc  6247d1f0  
I/DEBUG(252):          610289d0  62d355dc  
I/DEBUG(252):          610289d4  603fbfa8  /data/app-lib/com.gamedo.hlw.gfan-1/libcocos2dlua.so
I/DEBUG(252):          610289d8  6247d1c0  
I/DEBUG(252):          610289dc  6247d370  
I/DEBUG(252):          610289e0  6247d1f0  
I/DEBUG(252):          610289e4  000007f8  
I/DEBUG(252):          610289e8  62d35658  
I/DEBUG(252):          610289ec  62d355dc  
I/DEBUG(252):          610289f0  6247dd00  
I/DEBUG(252):          610289f4  6247d1c0  
I/DEBUG(252):          610289f8  df0027ad  
I/DEBUG(252):          610289fc  00000000  
I/DEBUG(252):     #00  61028a00  00007fd9  
I/DEBUG(252):          ........  ........
I/DEBUG(252):     #01  61028a00  00007fd9  
I/DEBUG(252):          61028a04  603f4220  /data/app-lib/com.gamedo.hlw.gfan-1/libcocos2dlua.so
I/DEBUG(252):          61028a08  5ef1d6b8  
I/DEBUG(252):          61028a0c  00000010  
I/DEBUG(252):          61028a10  62d355dc  
I/DEBUG(252):          61028a14  6247d1c0  
I/DEBUG(252):          61028a18  00000000  
I/DEBUG(252):          61028a1c  00000002  
I/DEBUG(252):          61028a20  00000008  
I/DEBUG(252):          61028a24  6247d1f0  
I/DEBUG(252):          61028a28  00000000  
I/DEBUG(252):          61028a2c  00000000  
I/DEBUG(252):          61028a30  60f28f1c  
I/DEBUG(252):          61028a34  61028b70  [stack:23911]
I/DEBUG(252):          61028a38  60f28f14  
I/DEBUG(252):          61028a3c  5f37dea8  
I/DEBUG(252): memory near r1:
I/DEBUG(252):     62c8c0d0 62d57b90 fffffffb 62d60ec0 fffffffb  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c8c0e0 00000000 00000000 62a82b60 00000813  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c8c0f0 000002d7 ffffffff 62c96d50 fffffff4  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c8c100 62c96e98 fffffff4 62c96f88 fffffff4  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c8c110 62cda088 fffffff4 62cda178 fffffff4  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c8c120 62cda380 fffffff4 62cda3a8 fffffff4  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c8c130 62cda498 fffffff4 62cda588 fffffff4  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c8c140 62cda890 fffffff4 62cda9c8 fffffff4  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c8c150 62cdab00 fffffff4 62cdac38 fffffff4  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c8c160 62cdacc8 fffffff4 62cdae00 fffffff4  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c8c170 62cdae90 fffffff4 62cdafc8 fffffff4  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c8c180 62cdb408 fffffff4 62cdb540 fffffff4  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c8c190 62cdb710 fffffff4 62cdb858 fffffff4  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c8c1a0 62cdb9a0 fffffff4 62cdbae8 fffffff4  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c8c1b0 62cdbc30 fffffff4 62cdbd78 fffffff4  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c8c1c0 62cdbec0 fffffff4 62cdc008 fffffff4  
I/DEBUG(252): memory near r2:
I/DEBUG(252):     62c8c178 62cdafc8 fffffff4 62cdb408 fffffff4  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c8c188 62cdb540 fffffff4 62cdb710 fffffff4  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c8c198 62cdb858 fffffff4 62cdb9a0 fffffff4  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c8c1a8 62cdbae8 fffffff4 62cdbc30 fffffff4  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c8c1b8 62cdbd78 fffffff4 62cdbec0 fffffff4  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c8c1c8 62cdc008 fffffff4 62cdc150 fffffff4  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c8c1d8 62cdc298 fffffff4 62cdc3e0 fffffff4  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c8c1e8 62cda740 fffffff4 62c96e40 fffffff4  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c8c1f8 62c89160 fffffff4 62c898b0 fffffff4  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c8c208 62c899f8 fffffff4 62c89b40 fffffff4  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c8c218 62c89c88 fffffff4 62c89dd0 fffffff4  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c8c228 62c89f18 fffffff4 62c8a060 fffffff4  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c8c238 62c8a1a8 fffffff4 62c8a2f0 fffffff4  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c8c248 62c8a438 fffffff4 62c8a580 fffffff4  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c8c258 62c8a6c8 fffffff4 62c8a810 fffffff4  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c8c268 62c8a958 fffffff4 62c8aaa0 fffffff4  
I/DEBUG(252): memory near r3:
I/DEBUG(252):     62c96d08 62cc2550 0000001b 62f5d2a8 62000400  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c96d18 345b0d94 00000001 00000039 0000002b  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c96d28 62cddc78 00000b01 62c8c0f0 62cdb540  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c96d38 00000000 6247d248 00000101 00000000  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c96d48 62c7e1b8 0000002b 62c96d28 00000b01  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c96d58 00000000 62c90600 00000000 62c96d78  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c96d68 00000000 00000007 00000181 000000cb  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c96d78 62c95c20 fffffffb 62cde188 fffffffb  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c96d88 00000000 62c96e08 00000000 ffffffff  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c96d98 0000005f ffffffff 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c96da8 00000000 ffffffff 00000354 ffffffff  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c96db8 00000000 00000000 62c95c00 fffffffb  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c96dc8 62d60ec0 fffffffb 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c96dd8 62c95bd0 fffffffb 62afe140 fffffffb  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c96de8 62c96e08 00000000 00000000 ffffffff  
I/DEBUG(252):     62c96df8 0000022a ffffffff 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(252): memory near r8:
I/DEBUG(252):     62cde168 74636566 6261662f 7a5f6f61 69787568  
I/DEBUG(252):     62cde178 696a6e61 6d2e6e61 62003370 0000002b  
I/DEBUG(252):     62cde188 00000000 00000401 699e1a18 00000004  
I/DEBUG(252):     62cde198 63736564 ffffff00 00000000 000000a7  
I/DEBUG(252):     62cde1a8 00000028 00000093 62cde000 03000701  
I/DEBUG(252):     62cde1b8 00000008 62cc3d20 62cde220 62cde220  
I/DEBUG(252):     62cde1c8 00000004 00000000 0000008a 00002001  
I/DEBUG(252):     62cde1d8 62c85948 00000476 00000003 62cde224  
I/DEBUG(252):     62cde1e8 62cde22b 62cde239 00000355 0000002b  
I/DEBUG(252):     62cde1f8 00000125 00010225 0103003e 00020034  
I/DEBUG(252):     62cde208 00030037 00020048 62a97e90 62483d78  
I/DEBUG(252):     62cde218 62a97908 62cde090 022dc000 01010101  
I/DEBUG(252):     62cde228 64020202 65727065 65746163 70695464  
I/DEBUG(252):     62cde238 00000000 0000002b 00000000 00000401  
I/DEBUG(252):     62cde248 bbe7d83d 00000013 61504343 63697472  
I/DEBUG(252):     62cde258 7845656c 736f6c70 006e6f69 0000002b  
I/DEBUG(252): memory near sl:
I/DEBUG(252):     62cc72c8 80000254 00010047 62d60ec0 62b66a38  
I/DEBUG(252):     62cc72d8 62cc72e8 62cc7308 0201c000 00000023  
I/DEBUG(252):     62cc72e8 62c959d8 ff000401 02623c3a 00000009  
I/DEBUG(252):     62cc72f8 6b6e696c 65746e45 62a60072 00000023  
I/DEBUG(252):     62cc7308 62d311c8 00000401 3c3daf3e 00000008  
I/DEBUG(252):     62cc7318 53746567 646e756f 62cc7200 00000023  
I/DEBUG(252):     62cc7328 00000000 62000400 7d9ffe75 00000005  
I/DEBUG(252):     62cc7338 6c696b73 0000006c 00000020 00000093  
I/DEBUG(252):     62cc7348 62cc71a0 03000701 00000008 62cc2468  
I/DEBUG(252):     62cc7358 62cc73b8 62cc73b8 00000004 00000000  
I/DEBUG(252):     62cc7368 0000008a 00002001 62c85948 0000027c  
I/DEBUG(252):     62cc7378 00000003 62cc73bc 62cc73c3 62cc73d1  
I/DEBUG(252):     62cc7388 00000355 0000002b 00000125 00010225  
I/DEBUG(252):     62cc7398 0103003e 00020034 00030037 00020048  
I/DEBUG(252):     62cc73a8 62a6be98 62483d78 62a6bad8 62cc7230  
I/DEBUG(252):     62cc73b8 0266c000 01010101 64020202 65727065  
I/DEBUG(252): memory near sp:
I/DEBUG(252):     610289e0 6247d1f0 000007f8 62d35658 62d355dc  
I/DEBUG(252):     610289f0 6247dd00 6247d1c0 df0027ad 00000000  
I/DEBUG(252):     61028a00 00007fd9 603f4220 5ef1d6b8 00000010  
I/DEBUG(252):     61028a10 62d355dc 6247d1c0 00000000 00000002  
I/DEBUG(252):     61028a20 00000008 6247d1f0 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(252):     61028a30 60f28f1c 61028b70 60f28f14 5f37dea8  
I/DEBUG(252):     61028a40 61028a74 603ff388 fffffffd 60ef58c0  
I/DEBUG(252):     61028a50 5f37de98 600ab578 00000001 6242a440  
I/DEBUG(252):     61028a60 fffffffd 600ab3b8 fffffffe 00000000  
I/DEBUG(252):     61028a70 61028a94 600ab790 5f37de98 00000001  
I/DEBUG(252):     61028a80 0000002a 6242a440 3d31d1d4 00000000  
I/DEBUG(252):     61028a90 61028aac 600a71bc 61028ad4 6244bfb0  
I/DEBUG(252):     61028aa0 61028ad4 00000000 61028abc 600a6b58  
I/DEBUG(252):     61028ab0 61028acc 6244bfb0 61028ae4 607dfa30  
I/DEBUG(252):     61028ac0 65bab968 6580d4c0 00000001 00000003  
I/DEBUG(252):     61028ad0 61028ad4 0000002a 3d31d1d4 00000000  
I/DEBUG(252): code around pc:
I/DEBUG(252):     5e0a5004 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(252):     5e0a5014 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(252):     5e0a5024 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(252):     5e0a5034 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(252):     5e0a5044 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(252):     5e0a5054 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(252):     5e0a5064 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(252):     5e0a5074 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(252):     5e0a5084 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(252):     5e0a5094 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(252):     5e0a50a4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(252):     5e0a50b4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(252):     5e0a50c4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(252):     5e0a50d4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(252):     5e0a50e4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(252):     5e0a50f4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
I/DEBUG(252): code around lr:
I/DEBUG(252):     5ea0fcfc 1afffff8 e59bb010 e35b0000 1bda54c4  
I/DEBUG(252):     5ea0fd0c e2844001 e1540000 daffffe7 ebda54c1  
I/DEBUG(252):     5ea0fd1c e24dd008 e30d1000 e3461247 e59102c8  
I/DEBUG(252):     5ea0fd2c e58d0008 e304b790 e346b2c8 e24ba050  
I/DEBUG(252):     5ea0fd3c e30e8e20 e3468247 e30d7d00 e3467247  
I/DEBUG(252):     5ea0fd4c e3e0500d e599e00c e5994008 e37e000e  
I/DEBUG(252):     5ea0fd5c 1bda54ad e599e004 e5991000 e37e000c  
I/DEBUG(252):     5ea0fd6c 1bda54a9 e58d100c e591e01c e59a3008  
I/DEBUG(252):     5ea0fd7c e5916014 e003200e e0822082 e0866182  
I/DEBUG(252):     5ea0fd8c e1c620d8 e3730005 0152000a 0bda549e  
I/DEBUG(252):     5ea0fd9c e5966010 e3560000 1afffff8 e5916010  
I/DEBUG(252):     5ea0fdac e3560000 0bda5498 e596e01c e5983008  
I/DEBUG(252):     5ea0fdbc e596c014 e003200e e0822082 e08cc182  
I/DEBUG(252):     5ea0fdcc e1cc20d8 e3730005 01520008 0bda548e  
I/DEBUG(252):     5ea0fddc e59cc010 e35c0000 1afffff8 e3e03004  
I/DEBUG(252):     5ea0fdec e58d3004 e58da000 e1a0200d eb67a01f  
I/DEBUG(252): memory map around fault addr 5e0a5024:
I/DEBUG(252):     5e00f000-5e010000 --- 
I/DEBUG(252):     5e010000-5e10f000 rw- [stack:23883]
I/DEBUG(252):     5e10f000-5e120000 rw- 
D/NativeCrashListener(847): Closing socket connection: FileDescriptor[200]
W/ActivityManager(847):   Force finishing activity com.gamedo.hlw.gfan/com.cocos2dx.lua.AppActivity
```

Comment: You are not kidding when you say hard to read. Have you tried debugging with breakpoints?

Comment: Problem is solved by manually reproduce the crash in ndk-gdb. The stack is  corrupted, the frame pointer in the stack is overwritten. I fixed the calling backtrace by  manually setting these registers : sp, pc, lr and r11(which is fp). Then I recovered part of the calling sequence.